# Does autofac initialize all registered components at app bootrap?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I just registered some components with builder, and I want to know whether all components initialize during application startup time? If so the app bootstrap may take more longer. But I see in spring.net IOC, it has an attribute of "lazy-ini" to allow target components to be initialized at first time user requesting a page. Can somebody tell me how autofac dealing with this? Much appreciate for your answers.

Comment: Why don't you add a break point in one of your constructors to find out?

Comment: You know: in all likelihood, it doesn't matter: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/ComposeObjectGraphsWithConfidence.aspx

Comment: Great post Mark! I've add it to my favorite folder :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, it does not construct any registered types when building the container.